# How to set bootstrap dropmenu width to 100%?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]How i can set bootstrap drop menu width 100% (from widow left to right )?

Comment: Cascading Style Sheets?

Comment: i try like this `.nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu { left:0; width:100%; }` but not working well

Comment: without some code, i dont think you'll be able to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add something like this in your `<ul>` and set the width

```
width: 295px !important;
```

or you can use this extension for drop down http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/